# Function to retain rows with >= 1 NA value (opposite of na.omit)

Tags: r

Is there a function that keeps rows with at least one NA, discards rows if there are no NAs...the opposite of `na.omit()`?  I tried `!na.omit()` but that didn't work.

Comment: Is this a matrix or a data frame?

Comment: This is for a data.frame

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the negation of `complete.cases`, i.e. `!complete.cases(x)`

Adapted from `?complete.cases`:

```
data(airquality)
head(airquality[!complete.cases(airquality), ])

   Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
5     NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
6     28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
10    NA     194  8.6   69     5  10
11     7      NA  6.9   74     5  11
25    NA      66 16.6   57     5  25
26    NA     266 14.9   58     5  26
```

Comment: Yep. That's how to use it. I think its name is misleading. Should be something like complete.idx, because complete.cases makes the user think it should deliver  .... cases, rather than delivering indices.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach using dummy data for a matrix, but it can be adapted to the data frame case easily enough.

```
mat <- matrix(runif(100), ncol = 10)
set.seed(2)
mat[sample(100, 10)] <- NA
```

We can use `is.na()` to convert the matrix to a logical one on basis of `NA` presence:

```
> is.na(mat)
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
 [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [7,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 [9,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[10,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

From that we can `apply()` the `any()` function to the rows, to return a logical index for rows with one or more `NA`s:

```
> apply(is.na(mat), 1, any)
 [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Putting this together we have:

```
ind <- apply(is.na(mat), 1, any)
mat[ind, ]
```

giving:

```
> ind <- apply(is.na(mat), 1, any)
> mat[ind, ]
          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]        [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
[1,] 0.6618988 0.01041453 0.9817279 0.007109038 0.77002786         NA
[2,] 0.8368892         NA 0.1150841 0.683403423 0.62512173 0.04217553
[3,] 0.1505014 0.86886104 0.1632009 0.929720222         NA 0.18467346
[4,] 0.1492469         NA 0.9746879 0.785878913 0.38814476         NA
[5,] 0.3570626 0.28487057 0.3490884 0.988902156 0.46150111 0.86784466
[6,] 0.9626440         NA 0.5019699 0.613952910 0.21867519 0.40264274
[7,] 0.1323720 0.15046975 0.8103973 0.710185730 0.06593551 0.57268500
           [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     [,10]
[1,] 0.35064257 0.9767552 0.2009347        NA
[2,] 0.02505036 0.3799989 0.9806000 0.3733586
[3,] 0.40110104 0.5603876 0.8289221 0.5743769
[4,] 0.97151543 0.4269434 0.8989719 0.8726963
[5,] 0.32372244        NA 0.4533770 0.1105549
[6,] 0.73319143 0.1153091 0.1474178 0.9527002
[7,]         NA 0.4400317        NA 0.5690021
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple inline option-

`is.na()` returns a matrix of booleans detecting NA values (same dimensions as input data frame)

`rowSums()` counts number of `TRUE` values per row

Finally, use native R subsetting for rows where at least 1 NA was detected.

```
data[rowSums(is.na(data)) > 0, ]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.